How do I make lyx in Rocky Linux (8) find /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base?
I'm trying to use lyx in Rocky-8 a derivative of the old CentOS distribution. When I tried to compile a .lyx file, I received an error stating that fontenc.sty cannot be found. in /usr, I did a
find . -name fontenc.sty -print

and found this file in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base
When I looked at Tex info, under latex styles, this directory was not part of the list. I did a rescan, and then a reconfigure, and then relaunched lyx, with no luck. How do I make lyx look in this and possibly other directories?
Thanks,

Could you perhaps include a trimmed-down LyX file triggering this issue?
